# pip search django produces time out error

Tags: python, django, pip

coincidentally, I run pip search django  command and I got time out error. even specifing a high value of timeout

Below the logs:

```
D:\PERFILES\rmaceissoft\virtualenvs\fancy_budget\Scripts>pip search django --timeout=300
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PERFILES\Marquez\rmaceissoft\Workspace\virtualenvs\fancy_budget\lib\s
ite-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\PERFILES\Marquez\rmaceissoft\Workspace\virtualenvs\fancy_budget\lib\s
ite-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\search.py", line 34, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, index_url)
  File "D:\PERFILES\Marquez\rmaceissoft\Workspace\virtualenvs\fancy_budget\lib\s
ite-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\search.py", line 48, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1575, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1462, in parse_response
    data = stream.read(1024)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 541, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 574, in _read_chunked
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
timeout: timed out

Storing complete log in C:\Users\reiner\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

however, another search command finish without problems:

```
pip search django-registration
```

**Is that a bug of pip due to the big amount of packages name that contains "django"?**

**Note:** speed internet connection = 2 Mbits

Comment: does search time out for everything?

Comment: apparently only when the query tends to produce many results:  

* pip search python  
* pip search django

Comment: I copied your call in my mac os x and it worked perfectly (take some seconds to run, but it worked ok).

Comment: @HugoTavares, after read your comment I tried again, and now the command works properly, and as you say "take some seconds to run".
Anyway, It would be a better idea that pip search command does not pull all results at once, and allow to paginate the results, even to add an option "per page" to define page size

Comment: added an issue to pip's issue tracker https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/498

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the --timeout option doesn't seem to work properly.

I can install django properly by using either:

```
pip --default-timeout=60 install django
```

or

```
export PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=60
pip install django
```

Note: using pip version 1.2.1 on RHEL 6.3

Source: [DjangoDay2012-Brescia.pdf, page 11](http://bitbucket.org/cstrap/djangodayit-2012/src/7e1333f0f575/DjangoDay2012-Brescia.pdf)

Comment: Coworker was having this problem. For some reason, that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thumb up for default timeout

Answer (score 2):

The pypi is probably overloaded. Just enable mirror fallback and caching in pip. Maybe tune the timeout a bit. Add these in ~/.pip/pip.conf:

```
[global]
default-timeout = 60
download-cache = ~/.pip/cache

[install]
use-mirrors = true
```

Answer (score 1):

There is too short default timeout set for pip by default. You should really set this environment variable PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT to at least 60 (1 minute)

Source: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/configuration.html